# WPF. DataGrid. Как при повторном нажатии по строке снять с нее фокус

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Есть таблица:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,449,0,0" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер ПК" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Прізвище" Binding="{Binding Path=First_name}"/>
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="видалити"/>
                    <Button Content="відкрити пк"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

При нажатии на любую строку, под ней генерируется строчка с 2мя кнопками. Не знаю как сделать, чтоб при повторном нажатии она убиралась, помогите плиз!

Comment: Не совсем понятно о чем идет речь

Comment: при нажатии на строку - она берется в фокус (выделяется). как при повторном нажатии убирать фокус (стандартно не убирается)?